# Assign Array Of Objects To Session

Tags: php

I got the following:

```
$_SESSION["content"] = $contentList->Value;
```

Where it assigns an array of objects to the session variable... When I then try to access the array it return 60 elements for example that are the size of the array but the objects in the array are blank... None of the properties in them are set.

Try to access:

```
$contentList = $_SESSION["content"];
foreach($contentList as $currentContent)
{
    //......
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning what you think to `$_SESSION['content']` ? if you use `var_dump($_SESSION['content'])` after the assigning the value, does the ouput look correct ?

Comment: You should serialize the array before storing it in a session.

Comment: Outlook doesn't look correct. I also have serialize and then unserialize the object in this case it only remember 1 out of the 5 properties, doesn't remember the others... Weird

Comment: PHP's session stuff will serialize the whole session before storing it, and arrays within it will be serialized correctly without doing anything.  Serializing your own stuff would be more busywork than any real fix for anything.

Comment: Please provide more information, it's hard to help if you don't let us know what you've tried and tested so far.

Comment: I tried the following: 1. store and edit it directly like above. 2. use serialize/unserialize... If I unserialize it only keep 1 property value, the other values get lost :-( If I do a var_dump on the session variable without unserialize i see the values are there so they get lost when i unserialize for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have included the classe definition before invoking sesssion_start()

Comment: Yes am sure that it gets included before session_start()